# Create site collection remotely on-premises with end user privileges

Tags: self-service

How can we programmatically and remotely create a new top-level site collection when

- Self-service site creation is enabled (any user in corporate network can create a site collection)
- we do not have Farm Administrator privileges (Admin web service cannot be used)
- we do not have access to server-side SharePoint servers
- We are on-premises (so we cannot use O365 Tenant)

If there are no other easier solutions could we programmatically send the site collection creation form (which is open for all the end users) using, say, WebClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes...Thomius for me also WebClient is the best approach..